# Make exports only the first word of a multi-word value

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***Given a makefile, like:***

```make
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"



# EDIT: I added the following line to address Etan Reisner post below. Thanks!
export foo

# A pattern-specific defintion, that matches both 'all' and 'dep'
% : foo += bar

all : dep ;

dep ::
    @echo '[makelevel="$(MAKELEVEL)"] foo="$(foo)"'
    @$(MAKE)

.PHONY : all



else



all ::
    @echo '[makelevel="$(MAKELEVEL)"] foo="$(foo)"'



endif
```

***Executing, we get:***

```console
# Overrides the Makefile-level-variable 'foo', with a command-line assignment.
$ make foo='cmd'
[makelevel="0"] foo="cmd cmd cmd"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
[makelevel="1"] foo="cmd"
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'

# EDIT! I've added the following lines, again, to address good pointers from Etan Reisner, below!
# Please, be sure to try it out in versions 4.0 and up.
$ make foo='cmd' -e
[makelevel="0"] foo="cmd cmd cmd"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
[makelevel="1"] foo="cmd cmd cmd"
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

Now, my question couldn't be more obvious!

There are here - clearly - 2 values, for the variable `foo`:

1. `cmd cmd cmd`. (The value at the *root*-make, as evident for the line starting with `[MAKELEVEL=0]`)
2. `cmd`. (The value at the *sub*-make, as evident for the line starting with `[MAKELEVEL=1]`)

Now, given that the variable `foo` was defined in the root-make (i.e. not the sub-make), and ***only*** there (either in the makefile level, or from the command-line for the `root`-make), so that the only value that the *sub*-make "sees"  for `foo`, is a value exported from the *root*-make. Agree?

So, assuming that, how is it then, that these 2 processes (the *root*-make and the *sub*-make) have ***two very different*** values for the same variable: `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `cmd cmd cmd` version is the pattern specific variable and those aren't what get communicated to the sub-makes. Global variables do.

That's why you get this:

```
$ make -rR
[makelevel="0"] foo="bar bar"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myname'
[makelevel="1"] foo=""
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myname'
```

The answer to the updated issue is one of variable precedence.

Use `@echo '[makelevel="$(MAKELEVEL)"] foo="$(foo) $$(origin foo)=$(origin foo)"'` in the recipe's and you get the following results:

```
$ make
[makelevel="0"] foo="bar bar $(origin foo)=file"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myname'
[makelevel="1"] foo="bar bar $(origin foo)=environment"
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myname'
$ make foo=cmd
[makelevel="0"] foo="cmd cmd cmd $(origin foo)=command line"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myname'
[makelevel="1"] foo="cmd $(origin foo)=command line"
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myname'
```

Which clearly shows why you get the results you get in each case. As the appended value is overridden by the command-line value again (and isn't re-appended because of the `$(MAKELEVEL)` split).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my post to add `export foo`. Now, `foo` gets exported even without a *command-line* assignment.

Comment: "...Which clearly shows why you get the results you get in each case." Because?

Comment: Didn't think it really needed saying but edited in all the same.

Comment: "and isn't re-appended because of the $(MAKELEVEL) split". What?

Comment: You have the `% : foo += bar` guarded in an `ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"` block so it doesn't happen in the sub-make. Move that out and it would and you would get `[makelevel="1"] foo="cmd cmd $(origin foo)=command line"` from the `all` match.

Comment: I've edited again, to show the case for a `make 'foo=cmd -e'` (*-environment-overrides*), Where the sub-make suddenly can see even those appended values from the *root*-make. Right?

Comment: I'll admit that I wouldn't have expected that behavior from `make foo=cmd -e` (and make 3.81 and 3.82 didn't do that). But I can see the changes in what make is doing now that I look for it. I'm not sure it isn't a bug though. More digging later.